# background flicker

Tags: c++, winapi, background-color

I am modifying the source code of a pdf viewe: SamutraPDF.

During registering the window class of the main window, the original code doesn't have

```
wcex.hbrBackground  = gBrushFrameBg;
```

I add this by myselft. But then when I resize the main window, I got background flicker.
The whole client area of the main window is covered by several child window, like toolbar, table of contents and the viewing area of the pdf file.

I tried to add `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` when I create the main window, but it doesn't help. I really need to give the main window a custom background.

Could you point me how to solve the flicker.

---

The reason I need a background for the main window is:

I would like to create two panels (each panel can view a pdf file) and between these two panels, I need a "splitter" which I can use to resize the two panels size. I don't want to really create a splitter bar, rather I would like to give a gap between these two panels. So I will see a "thin stick", which is just the gap, of the color as the background color of the main window.

Comment: Out of interest, is a single extra window that handles the dragging much over an overhead?

Comment: `I am modifying the source code of a pdf viewe: SamutraPDF.`

...SumatraPDF, perhaps.